# How much does it cost to make a MOOC universally accessible, as defined by the Americans With Disabilities Act of 1990?

Tags: reference-request, fees, disability, audio-video-recording, mooc

Is there any research/study/survey that tried to quantify the cost of making  a MOOC universally accessible, as defined by the [Americans With Disabilities Act of 1990](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Americans_with_Disabilities_Act_of_1990) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170318150158/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Americans_with_Disabilities_Act_of_1990))?

I am aware that the cost depends on several factors, such as the type of content the MOOC contains ( video / text / etc.).

The question is motivated by the lawsuits some educational firms received / feared to receive to due to lack of accessibility of the course materials:

- [Berkeley will begin removing more than 20,000 video and audio lectures from public view as a result of a Justice Department accessibility order](https://www.insidehighered.com/news/2017/03/06/u-california-berkeley-delete-publicly-available-educational-content)  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170317234832/https://www.insidehighered.com/news/2017/03/06/u-california-berkeley-delete-publicly-available-educational-content))  (published on  2017-03-06)
- [Videos for Stanford's CS224d No Longer Available](https://redd.it/4j7mh8)  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170318150350/https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/4j7mh8/videos_for_stanfords_cs224d_no_longer_available/)) (published in  2016)
- [Settlement Agreement (“Agreement”) are the United States of America (“United States”) and edX Inc. (“edX”).](https://www.ada.gov/edx_sa.htm)   ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/save/https://www.ada.gov/edx_sa.htm)) (published on April 2, 2015)
- [Agreements with Colleges and Universities Regarding Accessibility](http://udloncampus.cast.org/page/policy_legal#.WNaiHG8rJhF) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170325165841/http://udloncampus.cast.org/page/policy_legal))

Comment: Note that the incident that inspired this question isn't specifically about MOOCs but included much more general content, such as podcasts and videos of lectures. (This in no way affects the validity of the question.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby Thanks, good point, I'm also interested in the cost of making videos of lectures accessible.

Answer (score 21):

The question asks for studies or research, and I don't know of any, but I do have some first-hand experience.

Meeting the Section 508* requirements for Web pages used in such a course is effectively without cost if one starts out to make such pages accessible.  Retrofitting might cost as much as the original project, but the cost should be near zero for modern MOOCs.

Closed (or open) captions are very expensive.  Unless done at a foreign sweatshop, cost is $5.00 to $15.00 per minute, so something like $12,000 as a minimum, up over $35,000, for a one-semester course.  In other words, the captioning can cost more than the professor.  That's at least part of why some institutions employ ASL interpreters for class sections with deaf students.

*Edited to add:* I worry about the quality of the content for captions of university-level courses produced offshore at cheap rates, but have no personal experience.  I *have* experimented extensively with captioning through voice recognition for my own courses.  It's getting much better, but still requires extensive manual editing.  The $5-15 number given above could be reduced by using student labor, especially if the students are majors in the material being subtitled.

Captioning addresses the needs of the deaf.  Making course materials available to the blind means being sure that everything that is shown is also described, either by the speaker who is presenting or in a manner that can be rendered through text-to-speech.  The latter means being sure that there are good "alt" descriptions of images and that appropriate markup, *e.g.* MathML, is used for things like equations.  In my own discipline, computing, that isn't onerous, and the costs sort-of disappear in the weeds of getting the course done.  Things might be very different in a discipline like the visual arts.

*Section 508 is part of the Rehabilitation Act, not the ADA, but you still have to do it.

Comment: If captioning costs $5-$15 per minute, how does it become effectively free if you start out with it in mind?

Comment: It's the Web stuff that's effectively free.  The Web pages used in MOOCs have to be accessible, and one makes that happen by *not* doing things that would make pages inaccessible.  There's more info here: https://www.section508.gov/content/build/website-accessibility-improvement  (Captioning remains hideously expensive unless, as in my case, it comes out of the professor's hide, and I can caption only a small part of the material I'd like to make public.)

Comment: There was a question elsewhere about the quality of YouTube's automatic captioning.  You can find an example here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mzhHKHSefZU until the government finds out about it.  Note that George Boole's name comes out right the first couple of times, but is later rendered as "pool."

Comment: "It's the Web stuff that's effectively free." You mean text-and-diagrams HTML pages? All of this stuff, video, audio, and all the rest is "web stuff" (which I think is why I was confused by your answer).

Comment: The question isn't about the cost of MOOCs, it's about the cost of compliance, or accessibility.  It's the *compliance with ADA* part that's free with respect to web material.  If you're going to compose web pages, record audio and video, etc. none of that is free; there's a cost to all of it.  Of that, some of that is "web stuff," and there's a cost to making it.  However, there is little or no cost to *making it compliant* provided one plans to do so from the start.

Comment: Now I feel I understand even less. Are you simply making the vacuous claim that, if you plan to do something from the start then it's not an extra cost so the extra cost is zero?

Comment: @DavidRicherby Nope, I claim that building accessible web pages costs no more than building pages that will not pass the accessibility tests, provided one plans to do so from the start and so avoids the traps that make pages inaccessible.  Vacuous?  I don't think so.  Did you look at the link I posted earlier?

Comment: A page that doesn't follow unobtrusive javascript, or progressive enhancement/graceful degradation wasn't designed correctly from the start.  If the page follows those concepts, compliance is nearly free as claimed.

Comment: @BobBrown also, captioning is very cheap if you are reading from a script — as I'd imagine made-for-MOOC courses's videos and audio clips are. It's a matter of breaking up the text into digestible chunks and then there are some great programs that let you just go hitting a space bar in time to synch them up).

Comment: There is software that makes good transcripts if it's just one voice.  Let me know if you want me to try to remember which one I used with good results.

Comment: @aparente001: I've tried Dragon Naturally Speaking with little success.  It captures words, but the result requires extensive editing and then synchronizing with the spoken words.  Google's engine does better, but see my example above, where "Boole" got turned into "pool."  One can download, edit, and re-upload Google's subtitles, and that's mostly what I do when the subtitle task comes out of my hide.  Except in the case of major corrections, the synchronization is already done by Google.

Comment: @guifa So, who writes the script?  That just moves the cost around, but  doesn't eliminate it.  I can probably count the number of professors who lecture from a script on the fingers of one thumb.  (I work from a topic list so I don't skip material or get out of order.)    "...you just go hitting a space bar..."   No, I don't.  The idea that you can effectively double a professor's workload, and with drudge work, is "free" is a concept up with which I will not put.  The result of a law requiring that my work be universally accessible is that very little of it will be made public at all.

Comment: @BobBrown Well, I write the script, of course.  Speaking off the cuff makes sense in person, but if you're going to give the course to several thousand people where they can't ask questions for immediate feedback like in a traditional classroom, tightly scripting things is how I have always done it.  But I got a stipend to develop my online course that paid for the extra work, and any extra accessibility issues beyond providing a script that needed to be worked out was handled by the disability resource center, not me.

Comment: @BobBrown - I have had very good results with https://transcribe.wreally.com/ for transcribing multiple speakers (meetings). // In my experience, training Dragon to your voice gives good results for a single voice and good audio quality.  I have used it with an additional layer of software on top called KnowBrainer, which was helpful. // Chrome has transcription software as well but I like Dragon plus KnowBrainer better.

Comment: Providing MathML or raw LaTeX versions of what's written on the blackboard in a math lecture (physics is probably similar) I would expect to be a lot more expensive than captioning.  I don't know of any examples of that being done on a large scale.

Comment: @NoahSnyder I fear you're probably right.  We no longer have blackboards, so I'm used to doing things the hard way.